# How to import jQuery code in to Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, mean

I have Typescript code and I want to add jQuery code inside my Typescript code for MEAN Stack

```
$('.chips').chips();
$('.chips-initial').chips({
  data: [{
    tag: 'Apple',
  }, {
    tag: 'Microsoft',
  }, {
    tag: 'Google',
  }],
});

$('.chips-placeholder').chips({
  placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
  secondaryPlaceholder: '+Tag',
});
```

TypeScript Code :

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})

export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onLogoutClick() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.fmService.show('Successfully logged-out', {
      cssClass: 'alert-success',
      timeout: 3000
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

I want to add previous details in my Typescript code. Help me to do this using jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

**Step: 1**

Include jquery file in angular.json file:

```
 .
 .
 "scripts": [
     "src/assets/js/core/jquery.min.js"
 ],
 .
 .
```

**Step: 2**

Declere $ vairable in ts file before @component devorated

```
 declare var $: any;

 @Component({
    .
    .
```

**OR**

import * as $ from "jquery";